# R loop until condition matched, then go on

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, cumsum

I have a dataframe with numerical values in one row. Now I want to calculate the cumsum of those rows, until >=  1.
If this point is reached -> print for all those rows a counter, write in every row the cumsum for its counter, then look for the cumsum of the next rows.

Should look somewhow like this:

```
value    counter   cumsum
0.3      1         0.9
0.3      1         0.9
0.3      1         0.9
0.3      2         0.4
0.1      2         0.4
2        3         2
```

My problem is how to tell R to stop the cumsum, if >= than 1. Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know that there's a good way to do this other than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly, but maybe this one here helps:

```
value = round(runif(20, min = 0.1, max = 0.5), 1)

csumVec = numeric(length(value))
counterVec = numeric(length(value))
startIndex = 1
csum = 0
counter = 1

for(i in 1:length(value)) {
  csum = csum + value[i]
  if(csum > 1) {
    counterVec[startIndex:i] = counter
    csumVec[startIndex:i] = csum-value[i]
    startIndex = i
    counter = counter+1
    csum = value[i]
  }
  if(i == length(value)) {
    counterVec[startIndex:i] = counter
    csumVec[startIndex:i] = csum
  }
}

cbind(value, counterVec, csumVec)
```

Comment: This is a nice implementation *except* that you're growing objects in the loop. It would be much more efficient to set `n = length(value)` and initialize your vectors to the right size, `csumVec = numeric(n)`, and assign the values to the `i`th index at each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have updated the code and also changed the variable cumsum to csum (so that there is no confusion with function cumsum(). )

Comment: @Zingzang when I cut and paste your solution into R I end up with all zeros in the second and third columns?

Comment: Yeah, it wrote length(values) in line 9 instead of length(value). Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can calculate the cumulative sum, divide by 1, and take the `floor()` (round down)

```
floor(cumsum(value) / 1)
## [1] 0 0 0 1 1 3
```

This is correct, except that it is 0-based and the `counter` does not increment by 1. Fix these by matching the result above with their unique values

```
counter0 = floor(cumsum(value) / 1)
counter = match(counter0, unique(counter0))
counter
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
```

Having got the 'tricky' part, I'd use dplyr (`library(dplyr)`) for the rest

```
## library(dplyr)
tibble(value, counter) |>
    mutate(cum_sum = cumsum(value)) |>
    group_by(counter) |>
    mutate(cumsum = max(cumsum(value)))
## # A tibble: 6 × 3
## # Groups:   counter [3]
##   value counter cumsum
##   <dbl>   <int>  <dbl>
## 1   0.3       1    0.9
## 2   0.3       1    0.9
## 3   0.3       1    0.9
## 4   0.3       2    0.4
## 5   0.1       2    0.4
## 6   2         3    2
```

or perhaps capturing the tricky part in a (more general) function

```
cumgroup <- function(x, upper = 1) {
    counter0 = floor(cumsum(x) / upper)
    match(counter0, unique(counter0))
}
```

and incorporating into the dplyr solution

```
tibble(value) |>
    mutate(counter = cumgroup(value)) |>
    group_by(counter) |>
    mutate(cumsum = max(cumsum(value)))
```

or depending on what precisely you want

```
tibble(value) |>
    mutate(
        cumsum = cumsum(value) %% 1,
        counter = cumgroup(value)
    ) |>
    group_by(counter) |> 
    mutate(cumsum = max(cumsum)) |>
    select(value, counter, cumsum)
```